# Simple date_diff off significantly

Tags: php, datediff

I'm trying to use date_diff to compare two dates, but it's not even coming close to the right number. To troubleshoot, I'm doing a simple hard-coded test:

```
$date1              = date_create("2014-03-20");
$date2              = date_create("2017-11-13");
$diff               = date_diff($date1,$date2);     
echo               $diff->format('%r%d');
```

This outputs "24" for me -- so it's not even in the ballpark. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: With so much attention, I am surprised that no one asked Matt to read the manual, downvoted, and closed this as a mega-duplicate.  The regular defenders of SO must be offline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $diff outcome contains a `DateInterval` object. It contains the following:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 3
    [m] => 7
    [d] => 24
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 1334
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

By echo'ing `$diff->d` you'll get the day difference. If you'd like to have the total amount of days. Use `$diff->days`. Just play around with it.

Comment: thanks, i wound up playing with it based on your suggestion and @marcell's answer to get $diff->format('%r%a') which will show negative differences as well

Answer (score 4):

You are using format codes for [dates in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), but yet you are having a date interval, that has [different format codes](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

```
echo $diff->format('%y-%m-%d');
```

This will show the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the total number of days you should use the `a` format character. See more at [php date interval format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

```
$diff->format('%a');
```

output:

```
1334
```